# resource not found exception Resource ID #0xffffffff when working in list view

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

```
/*imports and packages*/

public class ShowBookmarks extends ListActivity 
{
private ArrayList<String> booknames;
private ArrayList<String> bookmarknames;
private ListView myListView;
private bookmarkListAdapter mybookmarkListAdapter;
String path="none";
public static final String FILENAME_EXTRA = "FILENAME_EXTRA";
public static final String PAGE_EXTRA = "PAGE_EXTRA";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myListView = getListView(); // get the built-in ListView
    listBookmarkFiles();
    mybookmarkListAdapter = new bookmarkListAdapter(this, booknames,bookmarknames);
    myListView.setAdapter(mybookmarkListAdapter);
}


private static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView textView_name;
    public TextView textView_bookmark;
}

public void listBookmarkFiles()
{
        String bookdir="nothing";
        String bookmarkNames="nothing";

        booknames = new ArrayList<String>();
        bookmarknames = new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
        db.setVersion(1);

       try 
       { 
        Cursor cur = db.query("BookMark",null, null, null,null,null,null);
cur.moveToFirst();
while(cur.isAfterLast()==false)
{
  bookdir = cur.getString(1);

  int p = bookdir.lastIndexOf("/");
  path=bookdir.substring(0,p);
          bookdir = bookdir.substring(p);

      bookmarkNames=cur.getString(3);

      booknames.add(bookdir);

      bookmarknames.add(bookmarkNames);

  cur.moveToNext();
}
cur.moveToFirst();
cur.close(); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 System.out.println(e);
}

finally
{
 db.close();
}



}

public class bookmarkListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private List<String> fileDir;
    private List<String> mybooks;
    private List<String> mybookmarks;
    private LayoutInflater myInflater;

public bookmarkListAdapter(Context context, List<String> bookz, List<String> bookmarkz)
{
    super(context, -1, bookz);
    this.mybooks = bookz;
    this.mybookmarks = bookmarkz;

    myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getBookmarkView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder bookmarkviewHolder; // holds references to current item's GUI
    //ViewHolder viewHolder1;
    // if convertView is null, inflate GUI and create ViewHolder;
    // otherwise, get existing ViewHolder
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(ListEpubActivity.this,"" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmarks, null);
        System.out.println("inside convert view");


        bookmarkviewHolder = new ViewHolder();


        bookmarkviewHolder.textView_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookname);
        bookmarkviewHolder.textView_bookmark=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmarkname);

        convertView.setTag(bookmarkviewHolder); // store as View's tag
    }
    else
    {
        bookmarkviewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        //viewHolder1 = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the list item (view) with the comic's details
    String bookName = mybooks.get(position);
    String realName = mybookmarks.get(position);

    bookmarkviewHolder.textView_name.setText(bookName);
    bookmarkviewHolder.textView_name.setTag(bookName);

    bookmarkviewHolder.textView_bookmark.setText(realName);
    bookmarkviewHolder.textView_bookmark.setTag(realName);


    return convertView;
}

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String bookmarkAddress="none";
    String fileName =booknames.get(position);
    String fileChapterAddress= bookmarknames.get(position);
    fileName=path+"/"+fileName;


                   SQLiteDatabase db;
               db=openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
               db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
               db.setLockingEnabled(true);
                   db.setVersion(1);



    try
    {
               String selectQueryAdd = "SELECT lastaddress FROM BookMark WHERE bookdir=? AND addresname=?";
                    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQueryAdd, new String[] { fileName,fileChapterAddress });
                    if (c.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        bookmarkAddress = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastaddress"));
                    }
    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                      System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                      db.close();
                    }


    System.out.println(bookmarkAddress);
    Toast.makeText(ShowBookmarks.this, fileName+"address"+bookmarkAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(FILENAME_EXTRA, fileName);

    intent.putExtra(PAGE_EXTRA, 0);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();


}

}
```

And the logcat says

```
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1018)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2105)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
    03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
   03-07 17:50:45.281: E/AndroidRuntime(10103):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am i doing wrong here? please help, i am trying to add the values which i take from the database to listview.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i just changed the code to this and every thing is just fine

```
/*<imports and packages>*/

public class ShowBookmarks  extends Activity 
{
 public static final String FILENAME_EXTRA = "FILENAME_EXTRA";
public static final String PAGE_EXTRA = "PAGE_EXTRA";
String pathofbook="none";
String dirFile="none";
String directoryfile="none";
String addrFile="none";
String bookmarkAddress="none";
String lid;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks);
    ArrayList<SearchBookmarksResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();
    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    //pathofbook= getIntent().getExtras().getString("bookpathfile");
    lv1.setAdapter(new MyNewCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
         { 
                  Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                  SearchBookmarksResults fullObject = (SearchBookmarksResults)o;
               Toast.makeText(ShowBookmarks.this, "You have chosen: " + " " + fullObject.getCid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       lid=fullObject.getCid();
       String pathofbook= getIntent().getExtras().getString("bookmarkFile");
       //dirFile=fullObject.getCname();
                   SQLiteDatabase db;
                     db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
                   db.setVersion(1);
                   db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                   db.setLockingEnabled(true);
                   try
                       {
                                  String selectQueryAdd = "SELECT lastaddress,bookdir FROM BookMark WHERE lid=?";
                                       Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQueryAdd, new String[] { lid });
                                       if (c.moveToFirst())
                                       {
                                           bookmarkAddress = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastaddress"));
                                           dirFile=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("bookdir"));
                                       }
                                       c.close();
                       }
                                       catch (Exception e)
                                       {
                                         System.out.println(e);
                                       }
                                       finally
                                       {
                                         db.close();
                                                       }
               Intent intent=new Intent(ShowBookmarks.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(FILENAME_EXTRA, dirFile);
            intent.putExtra(PAGE_EXTRA, bookmarkAddress);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                                    finish(); 

         }  
    });

}
private ArrayList<SearchBookmarksResults> GetSearchResults()
{

    String id="none";
    ArrayList<SearchBookmarksResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchBookmarksResults>();
    pathofbook= getIntent().getExtras().getString("bookpathfile");
    System.out.println(pathofbook);
    SQLiteDatabase db;
     db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
     db.setVersion(1);
     db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
     db.setLockingEnabled(true);
     //TextView t11=new TextView(this);
     try
     { 
      Cursor cur1 = db.query("BookMark",null, null, null,null,null,null);
      cur1.moveToFirst();

                 if(cur1.isAfterLast() == false) 
                 {

                     id=cur1.getString(0);

                 }

                 cur1.close();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
       System.out.println(e);
     }


                 if(id==null)
                 {

                         new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                         .setTitle("INFO")
                         .setMessage("No Bookmarks To Display")
                         .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                         {


                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        })
                        .show();

                 }

        else
        {
            try
            {
            Cursor cur = db.query("BookMark",null, null, null,null,null,null);
         cur.moveToFirst();

               while(cur.isAfterLast()==false)
                 {
                   if(cur.getString(1).equals(pathofbook))
                   {
                  SearchBookmarksResults sr1 = new SearchBookmarksResults();
                 sr1.setCid(cur.getString(0));

                 sr1.setCname(cur.getString(3));


                 results.add(sr1);
                   }
                 cur.moveToNext();
                 }
             cur.moveToFirst();
             cur.close();
             }

             catch(Exception e)
                  {
                    System.out.println(e);
                               }
            finally
           {    
           db.close();
           }

        }

     return results;
 }

 }
```

Comment: Down vote reason: Dumping the entire class will not help anyone resolve the issue. Please point out what exactly you changed in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
mybookmarkListAdapter = new bookmarkListAdapter(this, booknames,bookmarknames);
```

to

```
mybookmarkListAdapter = new bookmarkListAdapter(this, R.layout.bookmarks,booknames,bookmarknames);\


public bookmarkListAdapter(Context context, List<String> bookz, List<String> bookmarkz)
{
super(context, -1, bookz);
this.mybooks = bookz;
this.mybookmarks = bookmarkz;

myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

to

```
int resid // 
public bookmarkListAdapter(Context context, int resID ,List<String> bookz, List<String> bookmarkz)
{
super(context, resID , bookz,bookmarkz);
this.mybooks = bookz;
this.mybookmarks = bookmarkz;
this.resid = resID ;

myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: it is shown as undefined for its corresponding constructor, what changes i need to make there?

Comment: Have you also changed your adapter class?

Comment: i did
    `03-07 18:26:46.951: E/AndroidRuntime(10825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 18:26:46.951: E/AndroidRuntime(10825): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 18:26:46.951: E/AndroidRuntime(10825):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)`